# I keep getting an IPMI error when doing console redirection

Tags: java, centos5, ipmi

I did have the remote management portion of IPMI working locally and externally but it is now giving me an "Usage: java RConsoleApp <Aster Card IP> <Port>" error message.

This is a [Tyan GT20-B7002](http://www.tyan.com/product_SKU_spec.aspx?ProductType=BB&pid=382&SKU=600000031) barebones server and is running the IPMI firmware version S7002 R4.02

Any ideas?

I even opened up EVERY port externally and disabled firewalls.

**Edit**: *Sep. 14, 2011* Sent Tyan technical support an email.  I will update this when I hear back from them.

Comment: What client are you using for the remote IPMI?  What is the network topology between the client and the server?  Are they on the same network or is this remote over the internet or ?

Comment: I am using internet explorer for the remote IPMI.  It is ASTER's IPMI that comes with Tyan.  The server is on the LAN but I am also trying it remotely.  Network Topology?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a S7015. I managed to get it to work after:

- Flashing the firmware. I found it at
  https://www.tyan.com/Motherboards=S7012=S7012WGM4NR=downloads=EN
  (I know the motherboard is not exactly the same as mine or yours but this didn't matter.
  The BMC checks if the firmware is compatible before
  flashing)
- Connecting with https://ip_of_the_bmc instead of https://hostname_of_the_bmc
- Turning of my dns server so that my browser doesn't try to use reverse dns
- Clearing the dns-cache of my desktop
- Clearing the browser-cache of my desktop
- Placing https://ip_of_the_bmc in the exception site list of the java control panel

Answer (score 0):

I just used the python script from up here with old java 6.33 which I got from http://www.oldversion.com/windows/java-platform-6-update-33-x64
to make connection quick I made ipmi.bat file with the following:
|**ipmi.py -ip yourip -u urusername -pw yourpassword -l**|
You must run place the bat in the same folder where the python script is located.
work like a charm
Cheers